# How to change display css toggle switch with the same output on a different id?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, css

Hello I'm new to programming and kinda trying to get the same output on the customization switch proto.io provide, I'm having problem on how to make the toggle switch to print the same output.

Having trouble with java.

```
<footer id="change" class="blockquote-footer">STATUS: DISAPPROVED</footer>


<div class="onoffswitch" onclick="myFunction()"
                    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch">
                    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
                        <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
                        <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
                    </label></div>
```

The CSS

```
.onoffswitch {
    position: relative; width: 133px;
    -webkit-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select: none; } .onoffswitch-checkbox {
    display: none; } .onoffswitch-label {
    display: block; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid #999999; border-radius: 38px; } .onoffswitch-inner {
    display: block; width: 200%; margin-left: -100%;
    transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s; } .onoffswitch-inner:before, .onoffswitch-inner:after {
    display: block; float: left; width: 50%; height: 15px; padding: 0; line-height: 15px;
    font-size: 10px; color: white; 
    box-sizing: border-box; } .onoffswitch-inner:before {
    content: "APPROVED";
    padding-right: 45px;
    background-color: #39C234; color: #FFFFFF; } .onoffswitch-inner:after {
    content: "DISAPPROVED";
    padding-right: 22px;
    background-color: #940909; color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: right; } .onoffswitch-switch {
    display: block; width: 24px; margin: -4.5px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0;
    right: 114px;
    border: 2px solid #999999; border-radius: 38px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;  } .onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
    margin-left: 0; } .onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
    right: 0px;  }
```

//this is the javascript

```
 function myFunction() {   var x = document.getElementById("myonoffswitch");   var y = document.getElementById("change");   if (x.innerHTML === "APPROVED") {
    x.innerHTML = "APPROVED";
    y.innerHTML = "STATUS: APPROVED";   } else {
    x.innerHTML = "DISAPPROVED";
    y.innerHTML = "STATUS: DISAPPROVED";   } }
```

I'm trying to get the output like this.

[before switch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjKSc.png)
[after switch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exJXw.png)

Comment: Note: `Java` and `JavaScript` are different languages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you started with CSS, could also finish everything with CSS)

Simplified example:

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: orange;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 30px;
}

.onoffswitch-inner::after {
  content: "DISAPPROVED";
}
.onoffswitch-inner::before {
  content: "APPROVED";
  display: none;
}

#onoff:checked ~ .switch-status .onoffswitch-inner::after {
  display: none;
}
#onoff:checked ~ .switch-status .onoffswitch-inner::before {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="onoff">

<div class="switch-status">
  <div>STATUS: <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span></div>

  <div>
    <label for="onoff">
      <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

But CSS strongly depends from your markup.

Another way, with JavaScript only:

```js
let onoff = document.getElementById('onoff'); // checkbox id
let toggle = document.querySelectorAll('.toggle-txt');

onoff.addEventListener('change', function() { 
  // run function each time when checkbox is changing
  // this == the element, which run the function (here == checkbox)
  this.closest('.main-switch').classList.toggle('on');
  // find the closest parent with class '.main-switch'
  
  for (let i = 0; i < toggle.length; i++) {
    toggle[i].textContent = (this.checked) ? "APPROVED" : "DISAPPROVED";
  }
  // Google → Ternary operator.
  // (check the condition) ? (return value if true) : (value if false)
  
  // property 'checkbox.checked' always contains "true" or "false"
  //
});
```

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: orange;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 30px;
  user-select: none;
}

.main-switch {
  /* default switch */
}

.main-switch.on {
  background-color: #045acf;
  /* some CSS magic only for switching effect */
}
```

```html
<div>STATUS: <span class="toggle-txt">DISAPPROVED</span></div>

<div>
  <label class="main-switch" for="onoff">
    <input type="checkbox" id="onoff">
    <span class="onoffswitch-inner toggle-txt">DISAPPROVED</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. prime! this really helped me on my project !! uwu